# can we send applet through sms (binary data)

Tags: java-me, sms

Is it possible to send Java Applet through SMS.

The requirement is to download a Java applet through SMS to a mobile. Later install it.

Answer (score 1):

SMS is probably not going to work very well with this. The limit for a single message is 140 bytes (which gives you 160 7-bit characters), and (according to Wikipedia) the standard only supports up to 255 segments in a long message. This means you are limited to 140 * 255 = approx 35Kb, which is fairly small.

It will also get expensive very quickly if you pay per message sent or received.

You are probably better off just using the internet. Any phone that can run an applet probably has proper internet access.

Answer (score 0):

SMS is just 160 printable bytes :-) You can send a link to download applet at best.